# Ruby on Rails and Zurb Foundation Offcanvas not working correctly

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation

i just moved my ui (Rails 4) from Bootstrap to Foundation 5. 
I added a normal Nav for large screens and a Offcanvas Navigation for small screens. 
see here for more details: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html

When i click on the Menu the offcanvas navigation shows all links then i can click to content, open the navigation again, BUT, when i click on a link in the navigation, then, i am not able to open the offcanvas navigation, it looks like it is blocked, i have to refresh manually my view in the browser.

here is my code for that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : t('.siteTitle') %></title>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application'%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/modernizr' %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- NAVIGATION Top Bar -->
    <!------------------------>
    <div class="off-canvas-wrap">
        <div class="inner-wrap">
            <div class="contain-to-grid sticky fixed">
                <nav class="top-bar hide-for-small" data-topbar data-options="is_hover: false">
                  <ul class="title-area">
                    <li class="name">
                      <h1><%= link_to t('.siteTitle'), root_path, :id => 'newolu' %></h1>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <section class="top-bar-section">
                    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
                    <ul class="right">
                      <li class="has-dropdown active">
                        <a href="#"><%=t('.menus')%></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                          <li><%= link_to t('.restaurants'), restaurants_path, :id => 'restaurant' %></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                      <li class="has-dropdown">
                        <a href="#"><%=t('.changelanguage')%></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                          <li><%= link_to t('.english'), { :locale => 'en' }, :id => 'en' %></li>
                          <li><%= link_to t('.german'), { :locale => 'de' }, :id => 'de' %></li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Left Nav Section -->
                    <ul class="left">
                      <li class="has-form">
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </section>
                </nav>
            </div>

            <!-- NAVIGATION Offcanvas -->
            <!-------------------------->
          <div class="fixed show-for-small">
            <nav class="tab-bar">

              <section class="left tab-bar-section">
                <h1 class="title"><%= t('.siteTitle') %></h1>
              </section>

              <section class="right-small">
                <a class="right-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon" ><span></span></a>
              </section>

            </nav>
          </div>

            <aside class="right-off-canvas-menu">
              <ul class="off-canvas-list">
                <li><label class="first">Newolu</label></li>
                <li><<%= link_to 'Home', root_path, :id => 'newolu' %></li>
              </ul>

              <hr>

              <ul class="off-canvas-list">
                <li><label><%=t('.menus')%></label></li>
                <li><%= link_to t('.restaurants'), restaurants_path, :id => 'restaurant' %></li>
              </ul>

              <hr>

              <ul class="off-canvas-list">
                <li><label><%=t('.changelanguage')%></label></li>
                <li><%= link_to t('.english'), { :locale => 'en' }, :id => 'en' %></li>
                <li><%= link_to t('.german'), { :locale => 'de' }, :id => 'de' %></li>
              </ul>
            </aside>

            <!-- Content -->
            <!------------->
            <section class="main-section">
              <!-- Notice -->
              <!------------>
              <% if notice %>
                  <div data-alert class="alert-box info radius">
                    <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
                    <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
                  </div>
              <% end %>
              <!-- content goes here -->
              <%= yield %>
            </section>

            <a class="exit-off-canvas" href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
</body>
```

does anyone know why this problem occurs? 
my second problem is, that the text in the following code snippet is not aligned left, it is in the center. When i change it to right or middle, it is plus minus at the same position.

```
<section class="left tab-bar-section">
            <h1 class="title"><%= t('.siteTitle') %></h1>
          </section>
```

here is an image:

[image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7B0GIgz5gZra1Vmc2ZzbUI1Zm8/edit?usp=sharing)

hope somebody can help.. 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add data-no-turbolink flag to the tag containing you link and it will disable turbolinks for that link triggering a full reload.  I just tested it on on ios.  No need to disable the whole turbolinks gem.`<div data-no-turbolink><a href="/link"></a></div>` this should do it.

Answer (score 5):

The problem has to do with the `turbolinks` gem, which is enabled by default in new Rails projects. With this gem, the entire page isn't loaded, only some content (intelligently identified by Rails). Check the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/390-turbolinks).

To fix this will cause the application to be slower, and you will now see the full page refresh on every link you click. Nevertheless, just remove (or comment until there's a fix) the `turbolinks` import from your base `application.js`.

From this:
`//= require turbolinks`

To this: `// require turbolinks`

Comment: Edward's answer is better, didn't find that stuff in the docs before!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with the turbolinks gem and found this solution for rails 4.2.0 and foundation 5.5.1.

In your gemfile:
    
    `gem 'jquery-turbolinks'`

On the command line:
    
    `bundle install`

restart your server,
then in your application.js:
    
    `//= require jquery
    //= require jquery.turbolinks
    //= require jquery_ujs
    //= require foundation
    //= require_tree .
    $(function(){ $(document).foundation()});
    //= require turbolinks`

This fixed all the issues with the foundation javascripts not loading by making sure turbolinks runs last using the jquery-turbolinks gem.